# HTML get the inner html tags value onSubmit of the form in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hi I'm trying to get access to the value of the nested html tag 'option' on submit of the form, basically on submit of the form i should be able to access the value of option tag in the handleSubmit function.
note: the code is in a React component,
here is the html code:

```
 <div>
            <h1>Create notifications!</h1>
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Form.Group size="lg" controlId="email">
                    <Form.Label>choose your message</Form.Label>
                    <InputGroup.Text id="inputGroup-sizing-lg">Large</InputGroup.Text>
                    <Form.Select style={{ display: 'inline-block' }} size="lg" aria-label="Default select example">
                        <option>Click to choose message</option>
                        {mainNotifications.map((n, i) =>
                            <option key={i} name="selectMessage" /*this is what i want to get => */value={n.type}>{n.message}{n.type})</option>
                        )}
                    </Form.Select>
                </Form.Group>
                <Button className="button" block="true" size="lg" type="submit" >
                    Create Notification
                </Button>
            </Form>
            
        </div>)
```

and here are the libraries I'm using for it:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import InputGroup from "react-bootstrap/InputGroup"
```

Comment: Can you provide the full code? You appear to be using a component library for the Form. So advice on how to obtain the values from Form.Select may be misleading.

Comment: @carl thanks for your reply, I added the code with the libraries i use for it,

Comment: Getting a value of selectbox after you submit a form is not really a react-ish way of doing things. You should create a useState for selectbox value. Add onChange to Form.Select and update the useState everytime the value of this selectbox changes. So when a user submits the form you already have the value.

Comment: @Jiri Vitek thanks for helping !
when a user selects a specific option is it going to change the selectBox state?
cause what I want is to get the value fo the option he selected
thanks so much!

Comment: @Mindy Yes, that is exactly whats gonna happen. I wrote a simple answer to demonstrate what I described in a comment earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of your function (before return), add useState. For example:

```
const [selectboxValue, setSelectboxValue] = useState("");
```

Add onChange to your From.Select element:

```
<Form.Select onChange={e => setSelectboxValue(e.target.value)} style={{ display: 'inline-block' }} size="lg" aria-label="Default select example">
```

And then you can use **selectboxValue** inside your handleSubmit function.

Comment: Just be aware that in case you "pre-select" any option in the selectbox and user does not even open a selectbox to change it you will get an empty value in the selectboxValue. You can either set an initial value in useState. For example .... = useState("I like cheese"). Or add one option with empty value to your selectbox that will be default. For example <option>Please make a selection</option>.